# AJAX.NET not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using AJAX Asynchronous Triggers. I created a project in VS2010 and everything worked fine. When I uploaded the same code to my server AJAX functionality stopped working. I installed AJAX extension for .NET but still the issue persists. My web.config file follows

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" executionTimeout="3600"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/> 
    </httpModules>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <pages enableEventValidation="false" enableViewState="false" enableViewStateMac="false">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I add handlers/httpHandlers to my web.config file I am getting `500-Internal server error.`

```
<handlers>
          <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
    </handlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should first check framework installed on your web server.
according to your web config your application is in framework 1.0 but you added handler of framework 3.5.

**Update**
please updated you handler section and upload again and then check.
hi mad coder update your config with this code and check again

```
<configuration>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</configuration>
```

and add this handler to your web config

```
<handlers>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </handlers>
```

Comment: My .NET framework is 2.0 what should I write for framework 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 2.0, ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 is used. Write correct assembly version to HttpHandlers in web.config. See the documentation: [Configuring ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/documentation/live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx)